# RecyclerView OnBindViewHolder called more then 1 times for some recycle rows

Tags: android, xamarin, android-recyclerview

I want to clarify the **recycler behavior** in scrolling in one direction, for example from top to down.
As I can see, `OnBindViewHolder` can be called a couple times for some rows even if we scroll each time only to down. Below, I listed the `OnBindViewHolder` calling log with cell numbers:

```
1,
2,
3,
4,
5,
6,
7,
8,
3,
4,
5,
6...
```

Is it expected?

If so, what place I need to put an cell appearance animation in? In this situation when I put animation in `OnBindViewHolder`, my animation plays a couple times as well. What is common approach for this target?
Thanks.

Comment: What exactly is a cell appearance animation? Does it always fire when a cell becomes visible or only the first time? And does it fire when a cell is only partially visible or when it is completely visible?

Comment: The animation fires each time when a cell becomes visible. Right now, there is no checking on partially or fully visibility of cell, so animation starts to play right after as a cell appears on screen. But this is my next target to do the animation playing only after when a cell will be completely visible.

Comment: So you are already checking when a cell becomes visible, right? Then fire the animation right there. Or do I misunderstand?

Comment: Yes, you are right.

Comment: @kalabalik, thank you for you help, To be more accurate with your question:
"So you are already checking when a cell becomes visible, right?" -
Right now, I play the animation each time when `OnBindViewHolder` works

Comment: I have very simple RecycletView adapter which has only two overrided methods : `OnCreateViewHolder` which makes only a view inflating logic and `OnBindViewHolder` which contains only binding and playing animation logics.

Answer (score 0):

This works for detecting new partially visible item views:

```
recyclerView.addOnChildAttachStateChangeListener(new RecyclerView.OnChildAttachStateChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChildViewAttachedToWindow(final View view) {
            view.setBackgroundColor(0xffff0000);
            view.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    view.setBackgroundColor(0xff00ff00);
                }
            }, 2000);
        }

        @Override
        public void onChildViewDetachedFromWindow(View view) {

        }
    });
```

Detecting new completely visible item views is more complicated. You need to use an `OnScrollListener` and look for changes of the results of the following two calls:

```
layoutManager.findFirstCompletelyVisibleItemPosition();
```

and

```
layoutManager.findLastCompletelyVisibleItemPosition();
```

If I am not mistaken, you need to keep track of those items which are visible AND which you have fired the animation on.